# "ImportError: No module named 'jwt'" in Jupyter

Tags: python, import, jwt, jupyter, pyjwt

I am trying to import jwt (JSON Web Token) into Python.

Following [this](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt) I have installed the package. The package also seem to import in the terminal python environment.

```
>pip install PyJWT
>pip freeze
>PyJWT==1.4.2
>which pip
//anaconda/bin/jupyter
>which jupyter
//anaconda/bin/jupyter
>which jwt
//anaconda/bin/jwt
```

However, when I am trying to import jwt inside Jupyter, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'jwt'
```

How do I get the module to import in Jupyter?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the kernel?

Comment: Yes, getting the same result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I used a different Kernel.

After I switched Jupyter to 'Python[conda root]', package imported.